# Coefficient of $x^n$ in the series expansion of $\sqrt{(ax^2+bx+c)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

$\sqrt{(ax^2+bx+c)}$ = $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ...+ a_n x^n+...$

Is it possible to find $a_n$? And if it is possible, what is the value of $a_n$?

Comment: [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)

Comment: @aidangallagher4 Try to use non-mobile links.

Comment: Sorry — https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series

Comment: also you can try to find a suitable expansion using [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Using binomial expansion, I could not extract the coefficient of $x^n$ as the polynomial inside the root is of degree 2

Comment: @aidangallagher4 I read about Puiseux series but could not comprehend how will I use that to find $a_n$. Can you help me out?